# Spring Boot validation of referenced object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using a `NumericValue<Unit>` class from a custom packages, which I'm not able to make changes to. I would like to validate the percent field of my `MyAPIRequest` in my Spring Boot API. Both the `PositiveOrZero` and `Max` validation annotations works when the type of the field is an double, for instance. How can I validate the value inside this object, without putting the validation inside the `NumericValue` object?

```
public class NumericValue<U extends Unit> {
    @JsonProperty("value")
    private final double value;
    @JsonProperty("unit")
    private final U unit;
}

public class MyAPIRequest {
    @PositiveOrZero
    @Max(100)
    private final NumericValue<Percent> percent;
}
```

Comment: This question has been answered before. Annotate the field with `@Valid` to propage the validation to complex objects and collections.

Comment: But when I'm not able to annotate the value inside my complex object (as it from another package), how will that work?

Comment: Let the other team fix that because that is wrong, you need that annotation else it won't propagate.

Comment: That does not make sense for the provider of the class to annotate. It's an abstraction which wrap a "core" value with the given unit of the value. The NumericValue itself, does not know that the value represents and thereby not able to annotate. In one case it would be a percentage which should be `PositiveOrZero` and `Max(100)`, but in other cases the 1000 could be a valid value. That's the reason why I ask for a way to annotate the value fields using this class without annotating the value inside `NumericValue` itself.

Comment: As stated you cannot as that isn't how javax.validation works.